# After updating to latest iOS13.4 my iPhone XR gets shutdown even when the batter shows 20%

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

After updating to latest iOS13.4 my iPhone XR gets shutdown even when the batter shows 20%. Tried to browse more on this, it was explained that it is a firmware issue. Can anyone suggest how to recover from this, as its quite annoying to have such behaviour.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I’ll try and help you out here,

Go into Settings>Battery>Battery Health

What is the maximum capacity rated at? Usually premature shutdowns are caused by worn out lithium-ion batteries and can occur regardless of the device.

Comment: It's also very helpful if you **link** to where you saw this was a firmware issue so we can evaluate whether it's legit or not.  If it's "some guy" on a forum somewhere saying it's "firmware" (without citing a proper source), I wouldn't put too much stock in that answer as it would likely lead you down a path to nowhere.